# Query no devuleve valores - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
return Encabezado::with(['pool', 'client', 
    'details' => function($q){
        $q->select("detalles.talla_id", "tallas.talla", "detalles.precio");
        $q->join("tallas","talla_id", "=", "tallas.id")->get();
    }])->where('estado', 1)
```

Este código me devuelve el valor de encabezados con todas las relaciones menos con details(details es una relacion hasMany con la tabla detalles), necesito poder mostrar el encabezado con la relacion details que devuelve la siguiente informacion:
De la tabla detalles talla_id y precio, de la relacion que tiene detalles con tallas necesito tallas.talla.
El código que les muestro no bota ningún error, simplemente la relacion details me sale vacía.

Comment: ¿tal vez porque no hay registros que coincidan con la forma como estás buscando?